# What does a * do in front of a variable name?

Tags: c++, c

What is the effect of putting an asterisk (*) in front of a variable name such as in the following line of code:
`char prompt = 'y'` vs. `char *prompt = 'y'`?`

Edit: When I originally posted this question, I thought that I saw this asterisked variable in a Java sample program that came included in Netbeans. That was my mistake -- It was C++ code sample in Netbeans. I was searching for an answer in some Java documentation and could not find it which led me to ask the question here. In the end, it was a trick question that I didn't realize was tricky at the time.

The answer is that the asterisk has something to do with "pointers", which has to do with memory addressing better explained by [anyone but me](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). And, they are not used in the Java language but most certainly are in C++.

Comment: `char *prompt` won't compile in Java. There is no such syntax.

Comment: Try googling "c dereference operator".

Comment: @Julian This was originally tagged Java. (See revision history.) Hence confusion.

Comment: Oh. Hence confusion, I see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char prompt="something" is wrong since char is only one byte long so you can only assign it something that is one byte long like

```
char prompt='y'
```

**More elaborately** "something" is represented in c as a array of character so compiler will also shout that you cannot assign const char[10](note length is 10 since a null character is appended at the end of the string by the compiler) to char.It is just like putting of buckets of apples to a single apple and result will be total car crash.
On the other hand `char* prompt ="something"` is pointer to a character.Here prompt is pointing to the string "something" you can also use indexing on it like prompt[0],prompt[1] which will result in s and o respectively.

I am also assuming that you mistakenly tagged your question to java.

Comment: I was playing around with Netbeans and opened a C++ example -- but then later was trying to do the same thing in Java and confused the example in C++ as an example in Java. That was my mistake.

This is the perfect answer -- 1) Making me aware that this is C++ not Java, and 2) that it's a pointer. Thank you for the clarification. Sorry about the confused answer.

Answer (score 1):

That means it's a pointer. There is no pointer in Java.

So if you have char *str, in str you don't have something like "Hello World" but the memory address where the string "Hello World" is.